# gulp-sass is not installed

Tags: sass, gulp

I turn into my project and enter: **npm i --save-dev gulp gulp-sass**
Then I enter the team: **gulp**
[an error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oji0I.png)

[It is the installation progress before.](http://wm7111-wordpress.tw1.ru/2019/03/07/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/)
[installation logs here](http://wm7111-wordpress.tw1.ru/2019/03/07/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed it globally?

`npm install -g gulp`